# Spring Boot problem trying to verify if user is logged or not for any activity

Tags: java, spring-boot, authentication, spring-security

Holla developers , i'm trying to frame the spring security process on my app using maven as wrapper , and right now i'm quite confused about how could i set verifications about user being logged or  not in order to trigger specific functions on one of my controllers , lets say in my SecurityConfig file i set this :

```
...some imports....

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(
        // securedEnabled = true,
        // jsr250Enabled = true,
        prePostEnabled = true)public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    RenterService renterService;
    @Autowired
    UserDetailsServiceImpl userDetailsService;

    @Autowired
    private AuthEntryPointJwt unauthorizedHandler;

    @Bean
    public AuthTokenFilter authenticationJwtTokenFilter() {
        return new AuthTokenFilter();
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder authenticationManagerBuilder) throws Exception {
        authenticationManagerBuilder.userDetailsService(userDetailsService).passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
    }
    @Bean
    @Override
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }

    @Bean
    public Authentication authentication(){
        return authentication();
    }


    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.cors().and().csrf().disable()
                .exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(unauthorizedHandler).and()
                .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS).and()
                .authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/cubancoder/multirenter/**","/v2/api-docs","/configuration/ui",
                "/swagger-resources/**",
                "/configuration/security",
                "/swagger-ui.html",
                "/webjars/**").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/api/test/**").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated();

        http.addFilterBefore(authenticationJwtTokenFilter(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
    }


}
```

Then lets say i enable a service and its implementation to get all products through my controller

SERVICE:

```
...some imports...

public interface ProductService {
    Map<String,Object> getAllProducts()throws GeneralException;
}
```

SERVICE IMPLEMENTATION:

```
...some imports...



@Service
public class ProductServiceImpl implements ProductService{


    public static final ModelMapper modelMapper = new ModelMapper();
    @Autowired
    ProductRepository productRepository;

    @Autowired
    ProductDtos productDtos;

    @Autowired
    AuthenticationValidation securityApp;

    @Autowired
    RenterDtos renterDtos;

    @Autowired
    RenterRepository renterRepository;

    Authentication auth = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();

    public Map<String,Object> getAllProducts() throws GeneralException {
        Map<String,Object>dto=new HashMap<>();

        List<Product>listProducts=productRepository.findAll();

        if(auth==null){
            dto.put("renter",null);//IF NO ONE IS LOGGED

        }
        else{
            dto.put("renter",renterDtos.makeRenterDto(securityUser(auth)));IF THER IS A USER LOGGED
        }
        dto.put("list_ofProducts", listProducts.stream().map(service->productDtos.makeProductDto(service)).collect(Collectors.toList()));
   
        return dto;
    }

    private  Renter securityUser(Authentication auth)throws NotFoundException {

        return renterRepository.findByRenterName(auth.getName()).orElseThrow(()->new NotFoundException("SError","EmailNotFound"));
    }


}
```

No matter if user is logged or not always falls on user being null

```
     if(auth==null){
            dto.put("renter",null);//IF NO ONE IS LOGGED

     }
```

Any idea about how could i improve this situation?
Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that there is a single instance of `ProductServiceImpl` which is initializing `auth` at startup time when there is no user in the `SecurityContextHolder`. Instead, you should initialize `auth` in the method which ensures that the `auth` variable is initialized at request time and there is a unique `auth` instance for every request (avoids race conditions). Something like this:

```
@Service
public class ProductServiceImpl implements ProductService{


    public static final ModelMapper modelMapper = new ModelMapper();
    @Autowired
    ProductRepository productRepository;

    @Autowired
    ProductDtos productDtos;

    @Autowired
    AuthenticationValidation securityApp;

    @Autowired
    RenterDtos renterDtos;

    @Autowired
    RenterRepository renterRepository;

    // remove auth as a member variable because it will be a shared variable across all requests and is null when the class initializes at startup

    public Map<String,Object> getAllProducts() throws GeneralException {
        // initialize auth as a stack variable so that it is no longer shared across requests and it is initialized when a user is in context (at request time)
        Authentication auth = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
       ...
    }
// ...
}
```

Comment: Holla Rob ...did try to apply your advice but still keeps giving me troubles...could you explain a little more?

Comment: applying your logic got me right away in the not found exception of the private method "securityUser", not letting me expose the dto as renter null

Comment: It appears that this answered your question about how to resolve the `Authentication`. If that is the case, can you mark this as the correct answer? If not, can you explain what is happening?

Comment: Someone else found this useful...and im pretty sure im omitting something .But as i told you once i applied your code i got  the function entering in the exception of the private fucntion SecurityUser